# Is it possible to read the data from hyeperledger on event based without querying the couchDB?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have setup the Hyperledger network by following [this](https://github.com/CATechnologies/blockchain-tutorials/wiki/Tutorial:-Hyperledger-Fabric-v1.1-%E2%80%93-Create-a-Development-Business-Network-on-zLinux#create-channeltx-and-the-genesis-block-using-the-configtxgen-tool) tutorial and  had build a custom business logic in golang (chaincode.go).

I can read the require data (JSON format) from CouchDB by doing small shell script, however, my requirement is to read the data on event based i.e whenever an invoke command runs and completes, an event get generate and we should be able to read the data from it without querying the CouchDB.

So I have 3 peers, 3 couchDB, 1 orderer and 1 CLI

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Fabric has chaincode events built in.

You can create, using the fabric client SDK, a client app which listens for channel events.

Here the Fabric documentation:
[Chaincode Event](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peer_event_services.html)

And the nodeJS SDK tutorial:
[NodeJS SDK Tutorial](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html)